# Using transactional memory in (g)Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, transactional-memory

I want to use transactional memory in Fortran (preferably gFortran). I think there's a workaround by using transactional memory in a C function and calling this from Fortran, but I would prefer to do it directly in Fortran (if possible).

The only related information I've found was about [an implementation in an IBM compiler for Blue Gene](http://community.hartree.stfc.ac.uk/access/content/group/admin/HPC%20Training/BG_Q%20training%20course%20February%202013/Reference/Transactional%20Memory%20for%20Fortran.pdf) , however I am not using Blue Gene.

Comment: What is your platform? The answer may depend on what it is you want -- HTM support, or STM support. If you platform is BG/Q then you can indeed use the [XL Fortran TM support](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/compbg/v121v141/topic/com.ibm.xlf141.bg.doc/proguide/bg_tm_concept.html) with the [TM_ATOMIC and END_TM_ATOMIC](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/compbg/v121v141/topic/com.ibm.xlf141.bg.doc/proguide/bg_tm_atomic.html) directives, but I don't believe you can use GFortran to access this facility.

Comment: STM would be OK for a start. But I don't have a BG - I only have a Haswell server with Linux (x64) running.

Comment: Ok. Clarification is good. Good luck on your search. My only suggestion would be to perhaps track down the IRC channel where the GCC/GFortran guys hang out and ask them there.

Comment: Intel TSX is available on recent processors. Not sure if yours has it.

Comment: And it's debatable if TM is going to help your code. I know a lot about the BGQ implementation and it is definitely not a panacea.  Maybe you can share the code you are trying to speed up with TM.